# Display reviews for a specific restaurant Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display reviews and ratings on a restaurant profile.

```php
<div>
    <h1>Reviews</h1>
    @foreach($reviews as $review)
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star{{ ($i <= $review->rating) ? '' : '-empty'}}"></span>
                @endfor
                {{ $review->user ? $review->user->name : 'Anonymous'}}
                <p>{{{$review->value}}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Error**

> Undefined variable: reviews (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurantFinder\resources\views\restaurants\viewer.blade.php)

**Reviews Controller**

```php
class ReviewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/index');
        }

        $review = new Review;
        $review->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $review->restaurant_id = $request->get('restaurant_id');
        $review->value = $request->input('value');
        $review->rating = $request->input('rating');
        $review->save();
    }

    public function show($restaurant)
    {
        // $restaurant=Restaurant::find($id); 

        return view('restaurants.review', compact('restaurant'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking in the wrong place. to track the problem start with your route file. Search for the URL in the web.php file you will find the route there. ones you get the route, you will also get which controller and action are making this page render.

this issue is shown when you use a variable in a blade template but do not set it in the controller for use. In the controller, you can set this variable and you are good to go.

hope this help. incase of any issue feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

update your **ReviewsController.php**

```
public function show($restaurantID)
{
$reviews = Reviews::find($restaurantID); // Find all reviews model by restaurantID
return view('viewer',compact('reviews ')); // This will do $reviews = reviews
// now you can foreach over reviews in your blade
}
```

this [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views) is useful

Comment: is Reviews the review model?

Comment: Yes it is. it's exactly the `review` model you have